# 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' on serverless deploy

Tags: typescript, nestjs, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm running `serverless deploy` and I have this error, I already tried with the most thrown answers from StackOverflow, and also with the least thrown; After seeing the official documentation, I think I have the configuration in tsconfig.json and serverless.yml correct for this; The project had already deployed before, I went back to previous commits where it was executed correctly, but in that version of code I have the same error. I cloned the project from scratch on a clean laptop installing node, and dependencies again and the error persists, with some orientation but I always get the same:

```
Deploying my-project to stage dev (us-east-1)
Optimize: starting engines
Optimize: my-project-dev-main

× Stack my-project-dev failed to deploy (23s)
Environment: win32, node 18.14.1, framework 3.30.1 (local), plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

If you have any ideas or know of another open discussion about it, I would be very grateful.

I already tried with the most thrown answers from StackOverflow, and also with the least thrown; After seeing the official documentation, I think I have the configuration in tsconfig.json and serverless.yml correct for this; The project had already deployed before, I went back to previous commits where it was executed correctly

Comment: Did you try adding "type: module" to your `package.json`?